# How can one determine the fan of a toric Weil divisor of a complete toric variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

It's well known that there is a so-called cone-orbit correspondence between the cones in the fan of a toric variety and the orbits of the T-action on the toric variety. My question aims to understand the geometry of the toric subvarieties.

Let $\Delta$ be the fan of a complete toric variety $X$, and $l\in \Delta$ be a ray. Then there exists a unique toric Weil divisor $D$ corresponding to $l$, which is a codimension one toric variety. I would like to determine the fan $\Delta_D$ of $D$ by $\Delta$ and $l$, and get a combinatorial description of the closed embedding $D\to X$ using fans or the toric polytope. It would be nice if there are some references about it.

Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: The one-dimensional torus corresponding to the ray is the stabilizer, the quotient lattice corresponds to the torus acting on the divisor, and the fan is the normal fan of the ray. Equivalently, remove all cones which do not contain the ray and then project onto the quotient space.